# The function call Asserts.checkNotNull, asserting a variable to be not null, is marked that the argument might be null

Tags: android, android-studio, null, assert, illegalargumentexception

I'm writing an android application with a custom support toolbar. After setting the supportActionbar, I have to get the toolbar again, using `getSupportActionbar()`. Since it might be possible, that the toolbar is null, I want to assert that it is not. For this assertion I'm using the function `checkNotNull` from `com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Asserts;`

See the following code:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
Asserts.checkNotNull(supportActionBar); <- this line here is marked, 
                                           that the argument might be null
```

It seems strange to me, that the `checkNotNull` line is marked by Android Studio, that the argument might be null, since this is obvious, because thats why I want to do this check.

Do you know how to get rid of this warning?

Comment: The IDE might be checking that function and seeing that it throws an Exception when the argument passed is null (that's what that method is for), so it's then warning you. I don't really see why you're using that method though. You can just do `assert supportActionBar != null;`

Comment: as I know `assert supportActionBar != null` is just a check for the debug version, and also not enabled in Android Studio by default . This is why you should check against null and throw `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: It can't possibly be null though, since you just set it. Null or not, `getSupportActionBar()` has a `@Nullable` annotation, which is all Android Studio cares about.

Comment: Yes I know. So probably it would be nice if the argument of `Asserts.checkNotNull` is also marked as `@Nullable` ;-)

Comment: Well that's not really your question and this isn't where you report bugs to Google. You could just make your own function with the right annotation.